# How can I take focus away from all fields when I'm switching tabs in vimperator?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I have a frustrating problem with the firefox pluign vimperator. When I'm switching tabs with `cntrl + n`, if a tab that has focus on a field is open **along the way from the current tab to the target tab**, this opens firefox in a new window. How can I take focus away from all fields when I switch tabs in vimperator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Sorry I have to do a new answer, because it's too long for a comment.)

I have my keyboard mappings customized beyond recognition, but I use gt/gT or Ctrl-Tab to cycle through tabs. But the main thing I have trouble duplicating is that if I switch out of a tab while in insert mode and then switch back to it, I don't switch back into insert mode. I wonder if you have some setting that is making it focus the first text field automatically or something. (E.g., **nofocuscontent**.)

Anyway,

`:help map`

should give you the basics in mappings. You might do

`:nmap <C-n> gt<Esc>`

or possibly

`:nmap <C-n> :tabnext<CR><Esc>`

or put it in your .vimperatorrc to remap it automatically on load; there you can leave out the opening ':' . (Replace `gt`/`:tabnext` with `gT` or `:tabprev` for `<C-p>`, etc.)

You might even solve your problem just by unmapping or remapping `<C-n>` in insert mode to prevent it from opening a new window (unless you like that feature).

`:imap <C-n> <Nop>`

will make ctrl-N do nothing in insert mode, or you could make it move tabs too:

`:imap <C-n> <Esc>gt<Esc>`

or some such.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to test, because I'm having trouble duplicating the problem (Ctrl-N does not switch tabs for me, etc.) Have you tried:

```
:set focuscontent
```

?

(See :help focuscontent for more info.)

If that doesn't work, you might just consider remapping Ctrl-N to gt<Esc>.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. How would I go about mapping that? cntrl-N, cntrl-P don't switch tabs for you?